# How do I add append to this nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON object is

```
"msg"=[{"userName":"Mandy","emailId":"m@t.co","userCreated":"2011-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15"},{"userName":"Andy","emailId":"ab@r.co","userCreated":"2011-12-21 17:29:58","allowedDownloads":"45"},{"userName":"Randy","emailId":"re@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 10:18:19","allowedDownloads":"15"},{"userName":"Vandy","emailId":"vai@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 15:49:20","allowedDownloads":"14"},{"userName":"Sandy","emailId":"vrush@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 16:47:35","allowedDownloads":"14"}]
```

1)How do I add 1 more person so that "msg" is appended with

```
{"userName":"Wendy","emailId":"w@t.co","userCreated":"2012-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15"}
```

2) How do I add a property "hobbies" to each of these indexes, so that I have,for eg

```
{"userName":"Wendy","emailId":"w@t.co","userCreated":"2012-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15","hobbies":"skiing,football,hockey"}
```

3) How do I check whether the index "Wendy" has a hobby "hockey" ?

Comment: All this depends on the language you are using to create and parse your JSON string. Modify the native data types of the language and use its methods to convert them to JSON and vice versa. FYI, `"msg"=[...]` is not JSON and I cannot imagine in which language this would be a valid assignment.

Comment: the "msg" I have posted is part of a larger json object being echoed by a php script... :        {"succ":true,"msg":[{"userName":".......}]}

Comment: Does this mean you are using PHP? If so, you just have to prepare an array for the new person and append it to the array containing all persons and call `json_encode`.

Comment: no, the code I have posted is received by a Javascript file immediately on loading a webpage...I need to update the object locally, i.e. after a user has been successfully added after an AJAX request

Comment: Then you have to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object/array and manipulate it there.

Comment: that's what I'm asking you...how do I go about it ??? I've managed to convert "msg" to an object : This is what I tried :     msg[msg.length] = {}; msg[msg.length]["userName"] = "Wendy";

Comment: Well, you did not mention JavaScript in the beginning. And then it seems more to be a question about how to add a new element to a JavaScript array and is not related to JSON anymore. Just do `msg.push({"userName":"Wendy","emailId":"w@t.co","userCreated":"2012-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15"});`. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @dichakpianist: where you went wrong with the code in your earlier comment is that after `msg[msg.length] = {};` the length has changed, so then you need to say `msg[msg.length-1]["userName"] - "Wendy";` Or you can just do it in one step as `msg[msg.length] = {"userName" : "Wendy" };`. Or, best option of all, use `msg.push()` as mentioned by Felix.

Comment: please replace *nested JSON object* in title with something more relevant such as *javascript array* so that people dont come here looking for nested JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a Javascript array

```
  var msg = [{"userName":"Mandy","emailId":"m@t.co","userCreated":"2011-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15"},
             {"userName":"Andy","emailId":"ab@r.co","userCreated":"2011-12-21 17:29:58","allowedDownloads":"45"},
             {"userName":"Randy","emailId":"re@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 10:18:19","allowedDownloads":"15"},
             {"userName":"Vandy","emailId":"vai@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 15:49:20","allowedDownloads":"14"},
             {"userName":"Sandy","emailId":"vrush@t.co","userCreated":"2012-01-02 16:47:35","allowedDownloads":"14"}];
```

you can easily push a new element

```
  msg.push({"userName":"Wendy","emailId":"w@t.co","userCreated":"2012-12-21 17:21:49","allowedDownloads":"15"});
```

but to update a record you have to loop

```
  function update(username, property, value){

      for(var i=0; i < msg.length; i++){
          var user = msg[i];
          if(user["userName"] == username){
              user[property] = value;
              break;
          }          
      }

  }
```

to search also you have to loop

```
  function check(username, property, value){

        for(var i=0; i < msg.length; i++){
            var user = msg[i];
            if(user["userName"] == username){
                var propertyVal = user[property];
                if( propertyVal && propertyVal.indexOf(value) != -1){
                    return true;
                }
            }          
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can add one more record with:

```
data.push({"userName" : "Smit","emailId":"smit@example.com","userCreated":"2011-12-21 17:29:58","allowedDownloads":"9"});
```

2) You can add "hobby" like:

```
for(a in data)
{
    data[a].hobbies = "skiing,football,hockey";
}
```

3) For the last question, you can create a function. I'm not so good with javascript, so there might be some other option apart from this. But you can start with this code:

```
function getHobbey(userName, hobbey_name)
{
    for(a in data)
    {
        if (data[a].userName == userName)
        {
            var hb = data[a].hobbies;
            if (hb != '')
            {
                all_hb = hb.split(",");
                for(i=0; i<= all_hb.length; i++)
                {
                    if (all_hb[i] == hobbey_name)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }            
    }
}
```

And by calling that

```
alert(getHobbey("Smit","skiing"));
```

Will give you true or false.

Still there are lots of thing in which you can improve this function.

Thanks!